# Getting a next record when data is ordered by Date and then Id

Tags: t-sql

I need to provide get the Id of the next / previous record from a single table. Table fields of significance are Id and Date. An example of data:

```
Date         Id
2015/01/15   3 
2015/01/15   5
2015/01/15   7 
2015/01/16   4 
2015/01/16   6 
2015/01/16   8
```

As you can see, records are ordered by Date, then Id. If my current record is record with Id=5, a query should return 7 for next record, and 3 for previous. That means that a query will receive an Id parameter, and return the appropriate result

Does anyone have any ideas? I would prefer a common sql approach, not specific to a particular database system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table table
(
  Date Date,
  Id int
)

INSERT @table VALUES 
('2015/01/15', 3), 
('2015/01/15', 5),
('2015/01/15', 7),
('2015/01/16', 4),
('2015/01/16', 6),
('2015/01/16', 8)


SELECT 
  *,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @table WHERE [Date] < [current].[Date] OR ([Date] = [current].[Date] AND Id < [current].Id) ORDER BY [Date] DESC, Id DESC) AS PreviousId,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @table WHERE [Date] > [current].[Date] OR ([Date] = [current].[Date] AND Id > [current].Id) ORDER BY [Date], Id) AS NextId 
FROM 
  @table [current]
```

Using subquery should work, but the Id should be unique for same date

Comment: Id field is Identity column, so its unique. Still, your example does not work. If I run only first SELECT TOP 1 query (since I do not need to get both next and previous for each record, but only one of them for one record only), it gives unexpected results, and the problem lies in the [Date] < current.[Date]

Comment: Yes, the ordering of [Date] should be included also, see edit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can take advantage of `LAG` and `LEAD` functions like so:

```
DECLARE @table table
(
  Date Date,
  Id int
)

INSERT @table VALUES 
('2015/01/15', 3), 
('2015/01/15', 5),
('2015/01/15', 7),
('2015/01/16', 4),
('2015/01/16', 6),
('2015/01/16', 8)

;with cte as
(
select 
[Date],
Id,
LAG(Id, 1, 0) over(order by [date]) previousId,
LEAD(Id, 1, 0) over(order by [date]) nextId
from @table
)
select * from cte where id = 5
```

Comment: In which version `LAG` and `LEAD` were introduced?

Comment: I have added that to your answer, cos may still use older versions.